# Javascript: Modify code to add elements to an array/list

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium

Hey Guys,
Javascript newbie here. I'm trying to modify some existing to code to instead of returning the **count** of elements, to actually add each of the specified elements to an array/list

here is the original code from [Selenium CSS counter](http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc/)

```
private int getCSSCount(String aCSSLocator){
String jsScript = "var cssMatches = eval_css(\"%s\", window.document);cssMatches.length;";
return Integer.parseInt(selenium.getEval(String.format(jsScript, aCSSLocator)));
```

}

I then have to convert the code to python, which I am far more familiar with

```
        def count_css_matches(self, css_locator):
        java_script_code = '''
            var cssMatches = eval_css("%s", window.document);
            cssMatches.length;''' % css_locator
        return int(self.selenium.get_eval(java_script_code))
```

But changing the original code to return the array instead of an integer is where I get stuck.

Thanks for the help and the below is the error I get when I tried to run it in Python.

Traceback (most recent call last):
"D:\Temp\1TestingApps\Selenium\SeleniumRC\selenium-python-client-driver-1.0.1\selenium.py", line 1218, in get_eval
    return self.get_string("getEval", [script,])
  File "D:\Temp\1TestingApps\Selenium\SeleniumRC\selenium-python-client-driver-1.0.1\selenium.py", line 219, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "D:\Temp\1TestingApps\Selenium\SeleniumRC\selenium-python-client-driver-1.0.1\selenium.py", line 215, in do_command
    raise Exception, data
Exception: ERROR: Threw an exception: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update your python bindings you will have it. `pip install -U selenium`

Comment: Ok, I did that... What change should I be seeing though?   P.S. thanks for your great book on Selenium!!

Comment: get_css_count is now in selenium

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `eval_css` works, but if returns an array of strings into `cssMatches`, as you can get an string, and not a list, using `get_eval`, then you should JSONify the list in the JS scope, getting it as an string into python, and using `simplejson`, converting it to an python's native list.

Something like this, I guess:

```
import json

def count_css_matches(self, css_locator):
    java_script_code = '''
        var cssMatches = eval_css("%s", window.document);
        JSON.stringify(cssMatches.length);''' % css_locator

    return json.loads(self.selenium.get_eval(java_script_code)))
```

I don't know if you need a return, document.write, or something like that in the js code to get the string. Please add a comment if it's needed, and I'll add it to the code :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, but when I tried your code in Python, it actually just returned an integer, not a string:  <type 'int'> .      Maybe it would help if you just took the original javascript code I posted and got it to return an array of elements. Then the next step would be to "Pythonize" the code.

Comment: Look, in the official Selenium's reference, they convert an array to a comma separated string using `.toString()`, and then they split the values: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html. Check if something else is wrong, because it seems to be the way to handle this kind of problems.

Comment: Sorry, this is the link: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#executing-javascript-from-your-test